# 'decide not to' or 'decide to not' ?

Tags: phrases, verbs, infinitives

I came up with this question when I received an email from a committee with a sentence 'We have decided not to publish it', which seems really strange to me because the grammar I learned in English classes is 'decide not to do something' and 'decide to not do' was told incorrect.

I searched for answers to this problem online, but did not find a clear as well as persuasive answer. In terms of grammar, is 'decide not to do' correct ? If it is incorrect, is there a reason why people say 'decide not to do' even in official letters ?

Comment: You object to the order that is actually *correct* according to the very rule you stated. And you do it *twice*, so it can't be a mere typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each of *decide not to do*, *decide to not do*, and *not decide to do* is correct. But the last one means something different from the other two.

- If you have *decided not to do X* then you have decided. (And presumably you will not do X.)  And *deciding not to do X* is the same as *deciding to not do X*.
- If you have *not decided to do X* then you have not made a decision about doing X.

Comment: But [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decided+not+to+do%2Cdecided+to+not+do%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecided%20not%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecided%20to%20not%20do%3B%2Cc0) show which of OP's suggested alternatives is more idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's a really cool tool! Thank you!

Comment: @booksee Your question is a good one (though it's been asked here before). The apparently more logical choice ('decide to not V') is far less commonly used than 'decide not to V'. Possibly it's just a matter of which flows better in speech.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Blame the usage on *"To be or not to be"*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, I am pretty sure that they are both perfectly acceptable, and in actual fact the way that you say sounds strange is normal for me - I guess it is differences in tuition.